# Find which class is calling methods inside a class

Tags: java

Programmatically find where and all methods of this class is getting called or not called at all.

```
class blah {
    void method1() {}
    void method2() {}
}

class blahTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class classToAnalyze = blah.class;  
        /* DO SOMETHING TO DETERMINE WHO IS CALLING blah CLASS AND IT'S METHODS
           AND WHICH METHODS ARE NOT GETTING CALLED ANYWERE  */
        String sMethod = /* GET THIS VALUE FROM PREVIOUS OPERATION */
        System.out.println("Method which is not getting called anywere: " + sMethod);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Method which is not getting called anywere:method2()
```

How do i do this programmatically from java?

Comment: @sanbhat It's there, all right.

Comment: Write/Use an AST to perform such a task.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in Java? Any good IDE will tell you if a private method is unused. Edit (meant private, not public)

Comment: @abmitchell public methods don't get flagged down. I've seen it for private methods and the like.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reasonably do this, since you can never know who else might be calling `method2`. Someone could always use your class. `method1` is also not being called for all I can see, anyway.

You can have each method set a static boolean flag so that you know which methods were actually called, and then check these boolean flags, but a reflective/class object manipulation approach will not work.

Anyway, for private methods, your IDE will mark unused methods with warnings or notifications, if it's a good IDE. Eclipse will do this.

Comment: This is more a thing to write an agent (for dynamic determination) or some type of syntax/execution analysis.

Comment: @UwePlonus Scanning the entire classpath and any classes that use this? Blech.

Comment: we don't know if he wants this to be done statically or dynamically...

Comment: hi i want to do this programmatically from a java application

Comment: @UwePlonus I don't know either, at least until that last comment.

Comment: @Expert This is not a very good idea. Perhaps we can determine *why* you need this done in the *first* place and fix it there.

Comment: I need to generate rest service for a methods which are not dependent on any other methods.